# Cannot call module's function after browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify, require

I'm trying to make simple page with JS module that will do something with the page. I need to use node.js's modules so I'm learning how to browserify works.

My HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello world!</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var test = require("./test.js");
        test.init();
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my JavaScript (test.js):

```js
"use strict";

alert("here1");

var init = function() {
    alert("here2");
}

exports.init = init
```

I'm making a bundle with:

```
browserify.cmd test.js -o bundle.js
```

When I'm trying to open the page it shows "here1" but doesn't show "here2".
In browser's console I see:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined      index.html:9
```

Any ideas how to make module's function (init) work well?

Comment: because require is not a native js function, it should be used in your test.js as that is what browserify uses to bundle your modules

Comment: But how I can have access to the function defined in test.js from the html/embedded js?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put all JavaScript code which contains anything from Node in the `test.js` file which you are then converting with the browserify into te `bundle.js`. In your example you are using a Node function `require` in the `index.html` which is not going to be converted. Browser then sees function `require()` which he doesn't know and this is where the problem is hidden.

Simply told: all your javascript code (containing Node) must be included in your `index.html` as a single `bundle.js` which is a browserifed result from your source files.

**EDIT**

Browserify doesn't (by default) allow you to call any browserified function out of the browserified code. But you can make it available by attaching the function into `window` scope.

This is `test.js` (which is then converted to `bundle.js` by **browserify**) and `index.html`

```js
"use strict";

alert("here1");

window.init = function() {
  alert("here2");
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="js/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Hello world!</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 init();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The main problem that I don't understand how to have access to the function defined in test.js (when it is browserified) from html/embedded js.

Comment: Aha! The need of calling it from embeded code was not clear in the initial question. I edited the answer, it can be made by attaching your function into window scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is the top goog hit for "browserify cannot access", and I just wasted at least a couple hours not-getting-it myself.  Perhaps other posts and blogs and tutorials are obtuse, or maybe it's just me, but here's an example I wish someone had shown me:

```
const trie = require('trie')    <---you want to use this module like in node
```

Run this (after installing browserify):

```
browserify -r trie -s trie > trie.browser.js    (if node can find it, browserify should)
```

-r = --require [module name]

-s = --standalone [globally-scoped(!) var name for module in browser JS env.]

(you can also use the -o for --output option instead of redirecting with >)

Then in you browser code you can do:

```
const LexTrie = new trie.Trie()
...or...
const LexTrie = trie.createTrieFromJson(lexicon_trie_json)
```

This beats making an intermediary text file with a require, which wasn't working for me to get the module to the global scope until I did something like:

```
window.trie = require('trie')
```

...at which point it worked, but I knew there had to be a simpler way.

Hope this helps some dense person like me in the future when they don't get the browserify docs because they don't highlight the --standalone option....