# browserify can't call the function i bundle, it's not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, browserify

I have some issue with [browserify](http://browserify.org/) , i want to bundle the following node.js file project [upload.js](https://github.com/mauricesvay/SketchfabDataApi/blob/master/test/node/upload.js), i modified the file on the following code and call the file upload2.js on the same directory of upload.js:

```
var SketchfabDataApi = require( '../../index' );      
var Swagger = require('swagger-client');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var api = new SketchfabDataApi();

    function UploadModelBySketchfabdataApi(token,idinputfile) {
    //var file = jQuery(idinputfile)[0].files[0];
    var file = document.getElementById(idinputfile).files[0]
    if (file) {
        var fileName = file.name;
    }
    var fullPathFile = document.getElementById(idinputfile).value;

    //var fullPathFile = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
    //if (window.location.port != "") fullPathFile += ":" + window.location.port + "/";
    //fullPathFile = fullPathFile + '/private/' + fileName;

    console.info('START UPLOAD2:' + fullPathFile);

    api.then(function (client) {

    // This is how you authenticate your requests with the "Token" scheme
    client.clientAuthorizations.add("Token",
        new Swagger.ApiKeyAuthorization(
            "Authorization",
            "Token " + token ,
            "header"
        )
    );

    // This is how you upload a file
    client.apis.models.post_v3_models({
        isPublished: 'false',
        modelFile: fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(fullPathFile)),
        private:false,
    }).then(function (response) {

        if (response.status === 201) {
            // The model URI is immediately returned, even if processing hasn't finished yet
            console.log('After processing, model will be available at: ' +
                response.headers.location);
            var uid = response.headers.location
                .replace('https://api.sketchfab.com/v3/models/', '');

            // You can poll the processing status to know when the model is ready
            // See how `pollStatus` is implemented below
            pollStatus(client,
                uid,
                function (err, res) {
                    console.log(err, res);
                });
            window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/stealth/#/stealth/models3d/models3d";
        }


    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error("ERROR ON UPLAOD:" + error);
    });

}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("ERROR ON AUTHENTICATION:" + error);
});

}

    /**
     * Poll processing status
     * @param {object} client Swagger client
     * @param {string} uid Model uid
     * @param {function} callback will receive (err, result)
     */
    function pollStatus(client, uid, callback) {
        client.apis.models.get_v3_models_uid({
            uid: uid
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.obj.status.processing === 'SUCCEEDED') {
                callback(null, response.obj.status);
            } else if (response.obj.status.processing === 'FAILED') {
                callback(response.obj.status.processing, null);
            } else {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log(response.obj.status);
                    pollStatus(client, uid, callback);
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
```

Now i run the command of browserify,

```
browserify upload2.js -o bundleSketchFabDataApi.js -d
```

and here my call.js script :

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/sketchfab/SketchfabDataApi/bundleSketchFabDataApi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/sketchfab/SketchfabDataApi/SketchfabDataApi.js"></script>
............................
    UploadModelBySketchfabdataApi("mytoken", "myfile");
```

but i have always the same error on the console "*Reference is undefined*":
[image]

**UPDATE**
Ty to *dnitro* suggestion now i can access to my function with the window variable but i must keep doing something wrong with browserify because now my machine don't see my *fs* module return the text *fs.createReadStream is not a function* like in the screenshot:
[image]

any advice for that,ty in advance.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: I had the same problem; see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510404/cannot-call-modules-function-after-browserify/78173195#78173195

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browserify does not allow variables to pollute global scope. If you want to use one you should attach it to globals.

Here if you want `UploadModelBySketchfabdataApi` function available to `window`, you could attach it:

```
window.UploadModelBySketchfabdataApi = function (token, idinputfile) { ...
```

---

**Update**:

Browserify doesn't support fs module. See [compatibility list](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#compatibility).

You could use [browserify-fs](https://github.com/mafintosh/browserify-fs) which uses [level-filesystem](https://github.com/mafintosh/level-filesystem). they claim that:

> All async methods in the fs module are supported and well tested
>   (including links!)

But watch out for browser support:

[image]

**Installation**:

```
npm install browserify-fs
```

**Usage**:

Directly:

```
var fs = require('browserify-fs');
```

Or use regular `fs` module and at bundle time replace it with `browserify-fs`:

```
var fs = require('fs');

// CLI
browserify main.js -r fs:browserify-fs -o bundle.js
```

Or use regular `fs` module and use *package.json* [browser filed](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#browser-field) to replace it:

```
var fs = require('fs');

// package.json
"browser": {
  "fs": "browserify-fs"
}
```

---